# How can I check what version/edition of Visual Studio is installed programmatically?

Tags: visual-studio, registry

I could read registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0`.
However, it doesn't give me any information about the edition of it - Professional/Ultimate or whatever.

How can I get the information with programmatically (preferably python)?

[image]

Answer (score 49):

In Visual Studio, the Tab 'Help'-> 'About Microsoft Visual Studio' should give you the desired infos.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I forgot mention 'programmatically'.

Answer (score 12):

You can get the VS product version by running the following command.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -property catalog_productDisplayVersion
```

Answer (score 8):

Open the installed visual studio software and click the **Help** menu select the About Microsoft Visual studio--> Get the visual studio Version

Answer (score 6):

if somebody needs C# example then:

```
var registry = Registry.ClassesRoot;
var subKeyNames = registry.GetSubKeyNames();
var regex = new Regex(@"^VisualStudio\.edmx\.(\d+)\.(\d+)$");
foreach (var subKeyName in subKeyNames)
{
    var match = regex.Match(subKeyName);
    if (match.Success)
        Console.WriteLine("V" + match.Groups[1].Value + "." + match.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

Comment: This will work only if Entity Data Model (EDMX) is installed for all installed Visual Studio versions.

Answer (score 5):

Run the path in cmd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer>vswhere.exe

Comment: And if I have multiple versions of VisualStudio installed ( 2015, 2017, 2019 ) is there a way to get them all from the command line ?

Answer (score 3):

Its not very subtle, but there is a folder in the install location that carries the installed version name.

eg I've got:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   2008 Standard Edition - ENU

and

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   2010 Professional - ENU

You could find the install location from the registry keys you listed above.

Alternatively this will be in the registry at a number of places, eg:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Setup\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition - ENU

There are loads of values and keys with the string in, you can find them by looking for "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010" in the Regedit>Edit>Find function.

You'd just need to pick the one you want and do a little bit of string matching.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone stumbling on this question, here is the answer if you are doing C++:
You can check in your cpp code for vs version like the example bellow which links against a library based on vs version being 2015 or higher:

```
#if (_MSC_VER > 1800)
#pragma comment (lib, "legacy_stdio_definitions.lib")
#endif
```

This is done at link time and no extra run-time cost.

Answer (score 2):

An updated answer to this question would be the following :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -latest -property productId
```

Resolves to *2019*

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -latest -property catalog_productLineVersion
```

Resolves to *Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Professional*

Comment: Vice versa, though.

Answer (score 1):

All the information in this thread is now out of date with the recent release of [vswhere](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2017/03/11/vswhere-now-searches-older-versions-of-visual-studio/).  Download that and use it.

Comment: Comment is true. -legacy flag doesn't help if you need to know edition and version as in main question. I have installed 2015 and 2107. But vswhere shows that I have 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 14.0(2015) and 2017. So it almost usless for old Studios.

Comment: Interesting, I'm correctly detecting only VS2015 with vswhere.  Did you previously have the old IDEs on your machine?

Comment: I have all MS Management Studios installed. They have shell from VS. That's could be the reason

Answer (score 0):

Put this code somewhere in your C++ project:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
TCHAR version[50];
sprintf(&version[0], "Version = %d", _MSC_VER);
MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)szMsg, "Visual Studio", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
#endif
```

Note that `_MSC_VER` symbol is Microsoft specific. [Here you can find a list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019) of Visual Studio versions with the value for `_MSC_VER` for each version.