# detect Visual Studio 2012 version

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, envdte

How do I detect whether Visual Studio 2012 RTM or Visual Studio 2012 with Update 1 is running using EnvDTE? The DTE.Version contains "11.0" in both cases.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089389/how-can-i-check-what-version-edition-of-visual-studio-is-installed-programmatica http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008003.aspx

Comment: The most promising part (ie. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\ registry key) does not work for VS2010/VS2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 put the SP information under the Wow6432Node subtree - e.g. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing. However, since VS 2012 Update 1 is *not* a service pack, the SP value hasn't been incremented.

Possibly the best way to detect if Update 1 is installed is by checking the version of a component you're interested in. For example for Visual C++, check HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\VC\Servicing\11.0\CompilerCore\Version : for RTM it's 11.0.50727; Update 1 is 11.0.51106.