# How to know which edition of vs2010 do I have installed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, registry

I've seen [How can I check what version/edition of Visual Studio is installed programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5089389/684646), but the question remains, what will I find if the version installed is the 2010 Ultimate or Premium?

The answer selected as correct says *"go to the registry and find"*:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\[version]\Setup\VS\[edition]**

*Where **[version]** can be:*

- *For Visual Studio 2005: 8.0*
- *For Visual Studio 2008: 9.0*
- *For Visual Studio 2010: 10.0*
- *For Visual Studio 2012: 11.0*

*And **[edition]** can be:*

- *For the Standard Edition: Std*
- *For the Professional Edition: Pro*
- *For the Team Edition for Software Architects: VSTA*
- *For the Team Edition for Software Testers: VSTT*
- *For the Team Edition for Software Developers: VSTD*
- *For the Team Suite Edition: VSTS*
- *For the Premier Partner Edition (2005) or Shell Edition (2008): IDE*
- *For the Visual Studio 2005 Tools for the Microsoft Office System: VSTO*

But it does not speak of *Premium* or *Ultimate* editions released (that I know of) for 2010 and 2012 at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I went to the registry on a machine with 2010 Ultimate and on

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Setup\VS\

I've only found *VSTS* so, **Ultimate** is covered.

***VSTS is the name of Ultimate in the registry***

(But premium is still a question).

(And that's why this isnt an accepted answer yet).

Comment: Why don't you just edit the original answer?  Scattering info across multiple questions like this just isn't very useful.

Comment: What do you mean with *"the original answer"*? If I get the answer as I need it to be I'll be editing it.

Comment: I've edited http://stackoverflow.com/a/5090878/684646, Just in case you meant that. *(the edition may be waiting for peer review)*