# How to determine Visual Studio version with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to figure out a reliable, future-proof way to determine the installed Visual Studio versions using C#.

My first idea was to use the registry. But on my PC, I found several keys being named `VisualStudio`, but not belonging to a complete installation. For example, I've installed VS 2019 and VS Build Tools 2017 - but within the registry, I'm finding `14.0`, `15.0`, `16.0`, `16.1`, etc.

Is there any Visual-Studio-API that might could be used?

The deeper meaning of my question is that I have to make the following call supporting multiple versions of VS: `var developmentToolsEnvironment = (DTE)Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.15.0");`

Comment: You could maybe just try different values in `Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.x.0")` and see what isn't null

Comment: That's right, but honestly, I thought of avoiding trial and error

Comment: Check for version-specific folders on the disks

Comment: You could check the list of installed programs.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system

Comment: @BWA Not only it could lead to false info (some uninstallers failt to remove all the data) but Visual Studio has different folder structures depending on the version used. I would go registry.

Comment: What do you think of using `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`? Should this be safe enough?

Comment: Have a look at this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089389/how-can-i-check-what-version-edition-of-visual-studio-is-installed-programmatica

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visual Studio setup configuration API for discovering instances of Visual Studio 2017 and newer: [Visual Studio Setup Configuration Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-setup-samples).