# Using Git in VS Community 2022, I created a new branch. This deleted the folder I had running after VS crashed. Why?

Tags: git, visual-studio

Is there something wrong with Git's version control for Visual Studio Community 2022, that it deletes entire branches and files and folders within windows explorer?

I previously checked out an early commit in the branch history, but now even the file that that commit represents appears to be gone.

1. I created new branch from an earlier commit for a file that was in a folder called 'src'.
2. In the process, visual studio crashes.
3. Now the 'src' folder no longer exists.  The repo still exists, but I can't find the file to open in visual studio which lets me view the repo or the original src code the file contained.

Comment: Please include the steps to reproduce this issue. BTW this doesn't seem to be related to C++, so if not then please remove the C++ tag.

Comment: Included the steps... that's really all that happened, unless you need something more specific.  If so, how would I obtain such data as you request?  Eg. Obtain info on the exact commit I was looking at?

Comment: Does it crash with any error message/error code?

Comment: No, it didn't give that

Comment: Please include VS 2022 version number. Also, it seems this kind of issue is reported by many users (example, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs2022-keeps-crashing-when-switching-git-branches/1630958#T-N1641364).

Comment: How do I look at the version number?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5089489/4688321

Comment: oh ok version 17.1.0

Comment: This looks like a bug, you can raise an issue on [Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home).